# Listas ordenadas embaixo de outra Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte menu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu poderia fazer para que fique dessa forma:

```
Importação | Exportação | Curso de Instrutor | Assessoria Jurídica

------------------------- (aqui seria uma linha (hr))

Vendas | Consultores | Relatórios
```

O código que tenho é esse:

```
<div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Importação</a>
    </li>
    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exportação</a>
    </li>
    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Curso de Instrutor</a>
    </li>
    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Assessoria Jurídica</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primeiramente essa resposta é uma GAMBIARRA!**(e não está 100% a animação do *collapse*). A forma como vc montou essa `Nav` está totalmente equivocada se vc for verificar a documentação oficial do Bootstrap 4. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Pra começar vc tem duas `Nav` com o mesmo `ID`, e tem apenas um `button` para abrir duas nav diferentes... essa estrutura está errada de acordo com a documentação... Vc teria que refazer essa nav e incluir todos os itens dentro dela, porem ajustando o CSS para ficar do jeito que gostaria e **não** colocar mais um bloco de HTML com a `Nav` no seu documento

Ok agora vamos ao problema. Primeiro mude o nome do `ID` da segunda `nav`, agora crie um CSS para mostrar a segunda `nav` caso a primeira `nav` receba a classe `show` vinda pelo script.

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse.show + .collapse {
    display: block;
}
```

Assim se a primeira nav for mostrada a segunda é mostrada também!

Veja o código funcionando. Porém não sei se no seu projeto vai funcionar, pois pode sofrer com algum css que vc já tenha feito ai. Além disso, ***recomendo fortemente que vc reveja a estrutura dessas `navs`*** para ver a melhor forma de colocar os dois menus em uma `nav` só, e não usar duas `navs` da forma como vc fez...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>
        .collapse.navbar-collapse.show + .collapse {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Importação</a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exportação</a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Curso de Instrutor</a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Assessoria Jurídica</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Vendas</a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Consultores</a>
                    </li>
                    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Relatórios</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui dessa forma, mas não sei se é a correta. Fiquem à vontade de me corrigirem.

```
<div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Importação</a>
    </li>
    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exportação</a>
    </li>
    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Curso de Instrutor</a>
    </li>
    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Assessoria Jurídica</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Vendas</a>
    </li>
    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Consultores</a>
    </li>
    <span class="linha-vertical"></span>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Relatórios</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara não sei se é o seu objetivo, mas quando a tela está pequena e o Menu fica "encolhido" dentro do botão de menu ao abri-lo só aparecem os itens de primeira Nav, a segunda Nav os itens não aparecem quando clica no btn do Menu...

Comment: Olá Hugo. Na verdade aparece, mas acaba sobrepondo uma parte da outra kkkkkk. Teria algum outro modo de eu resolver isso?

Comment: Cara coloquei uma resposta ai, como vc pode ver ela vai abrir as duas Nav, mas a estrutura do HTML desse componente está totalmente comprometida... o correto seria vc começar de novo, pois a estrutura do html está totalmente errada do ponto de vista da documentação e não teria como funcionar se não fosse pela gambeta que fiz no CSS, mesmo ssim não está 100%... Qq coisa comenta lá na resposta.

Comment: Olá hugo. Certo. Esse é um projeto de um cliente que já tem um site, mesmo eu já ter apresentando um novo layout, ele quer permanecer com a interface atual, porém a estrutura atual  é bem antiga, desenvolvida com tables, etc. Pelo que vi, é datada em 2003. Aceitei o desafio, já alterei todo o conteúdo para o Bootstrap, mas estou com dificuldades exatamente no menu. Vou testar seu código e qualquer coisa volto aqui. Muito obrigado mais uma vez pela força.